# Convention for Referring to ActiveRecord::Relation objects within specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a spec like the following:

```
describe ".some_class_method" do
  it "returns an ActiveRecord::Relation containing all Foo records that are active" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Just curious if abbreviating the text 'ActiveRecord::Relation' in the Description to 'ARR' is conventional, or if there is another way to abbreviate "ActiveRecord::Relation" in the rails community.

If that is conventional: the example would look like this:

```
describe ".some_class_method" do
  it "returns an ARR containing all Foo records that are active" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no convention for `ActiveRecord::Relation` of short form like `ARR`. If you want you can write like this. But you have to also keep in mind, if someone else look into that code and might get confused. So better to write elaborately so that others can easily understand what is going on there. But end of the day its your choice.